# Why can't I place an else-if statement in a for loop?

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop

Probably a super dumb question but here's my code:

```
if (currentItem.Name == "MicrometerTags.index")
{
    histIndex = Convert.ToInt32(currentValue);
}

for (int k = 1; k <= 20; k++)
{
    else if (currentItem.Name == "MicrometerTags.meas" + k)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default["meas" + k] = currentValue;
    }
}
```

Visual studio is telling me the first `{` under the for loop there has an error because it is expecting a `}`. But you can see my closing brace right there? I'm thinking the else-if statement is doing something wrong here.

EDIT: Okay I didn't know you couldn't do this. Is there then a better way to check if `currentItem` is equal to one of my 20 measurements rather than manually writing out 20 else if statements?

EDIT2: Here's the code I was trying to make. Thanks to BlueMonkMN for the solution.

```
            if (currentItem.Name == "MicrometerTags.index")
            {
                histIndex = Convert.ToInt32(currentValue);
            }

            else for (int k = 1; k <= 20; k++)
            {
                if (currentItem.Name == "MicrometerTags.meas" + k)
                {
                    Properties.Settings.Default["meas" + k] = currentValue;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Because the language specification says so?

Comment: By starting the `for` loop, you've broken the connection between the `if` and `else if`. There's no logical way this could work.

Comment: You can only put an `else-if` *immediately* after a preceding `if`. This is an error because there is a `for` in the way.

Comment: the `else if` requires an `if` block. Just replace the `else if` with an `if` and you are fine

Comment: Move the word `else` (and nothing else) before the `for` because you don't want to execute the `for` loop unless the first `if` is false.

Comment: @UweKeim doesn't help explain to me why I can't do it. See below your comment for more helpful explanations

Comment: @BlueMonkMN That's the answer I was looking for thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closing bracket of after the if statement effectively closes the if statement, at which point there's no more active "if block"

```
if (something == true)
{  // open the if block

} // close the if block

// no more if block in action here...
```

In order for an else to work, it needs to come immediately after that closing bracket:

```
if (something == true)
{  // open the if block

} // close the if block

else // next statement must be else for this to work
{  // open else block

}  // close else block
```

Commonly, this is coded in the following syntax:

```
if (someCondition) {
    // if true do this
} else {
    // otherwise do this
}
```

Note that the else still is the next statement after the closing bracket of the if block.

The reason yours isn't working is that you have other statements between the closing if bracket and the else statement.  Logically, I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but syntax-wise, the following are legal:

```
if (someCondition == true) {
    // do stuff 
} else {
    for(int i = 0; i < someCount; i++) {
        // do stuff
    }   
}

for (int i = 0; i < someCount; i++) {

    if (someCondition == true) {
        // do stuff
    } else {
        // do other stuff
    }

}
```

Note the order in which if and for blocks are opened and closed.  If the IF opens first, it must close last.  If the for opens first, it must close last (aka, first in last out pattern).  This pattern is fundemental to just about any programming language and isn't limited only to ifs and fors, but to any block-level programming (even namespaces, classes, methods, etc).

This is also applicable to nested logic:

```
if (condition1 == true) {

    if (condtion2 == true) 
    {

        // stuff

    }   // end condition2's if block 
    else 
    {

        // stuff

    }   // end condition2's else block


} // end condition 1's if block
else 
{

    // other stuff

}   // end condition 1's else block
```

Comment: This is perfect thanks for clearing this up for me